# Does typescript automatically accept undeclared subtypes as function arguments?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm passing an object of type `TestInput` into a method `quadrant` that is expecting an argument of type `CoordinatesMeta`.

So this is the method:

```
quadrant(c:CoordinatesMeta) {}
```

The `TestInput` type has all the properties that `CoordinatesMeta` has.

Do we need to declare to Typescript that calling:

```
quadrant(t) // t has TestInput type
```

Should be OK, because `t` has all the required properties?

This is a minimal reproducible example:

```
interface Center {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

interface MetaCoordinates {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  c: Center;
}

declare function quadrant(MC: MetaCoordinates): number; 

interface TestInput {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  c: Center;
  q: number;
}
const c: Center = Object.freeze({ x: 100, y: 100 });
const input: TestInput = { x: 99, y: 100, c, q: 1 };

console.log(quadrant(input));
```

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-mgdvrv?file=index.ts)

and it runs without errors, so I just wanted to make sure I'm getting the semantics right?

Comment: TypeScript is structurally typed.

Comment: You got it right. The TypeScript [documentation of interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces) explains it in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it right. The TypeScript [documentation of interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces) explains it in the first paragraph:

> An interface declaration is another way to name an object type:
>
> ```
> interface Point {
>   x: number;
>   y: number;
> }
>
> function printCoord(pt: Point) {
>   console.log("The coordinate's x value is " + pt.x);
>   console.log("The coordinate's y value is " + pt.y);
> }
>
> printCoord({ x: 100, y: 100 });
> ```
>
> Just like when we used a type alias above, the example works just as if we had used an anonymous object type. TypeScript is only concerned with the *structure* of the value we passed to `printCoord` - it only cares that it has the expected properties. Being concerned only with the structure and capabilities of types is why we call TypeScript a *structurally typed* type system.

Applied to your code, this means that as long as the type of `input` has all required properties of type `MetaCoordinates`, with the same (or compatible) types, the function `quadrant()` accepts `input` as argument.

This is just a particular type of assignment. Any object of type `TestInput` can be assigned to a variable of type `MetaCoordinates` because it has all the properties of type `MetaCoordinates` and some extra properties that the type `MetaCoordinates` does not know and does not care about.

Returning a value from a function, storing the value returned by a function are other examples of assignments. All of them allow to put a richer object into a variable of a type with less properties.

The types of the properties must be the same or the properties must be assignable as discussed here. However, it does not allow to use an object literal with excess properties to initialize a variable of some type.

This is rejected:

```js
const mc: MetaCoordinates = { x: 99, y: 100, c, q: 1 };
```

But this is perfectly fine:

```js
const input: TestInput = { x: 99, y: 100, c, q: 1 };
const mc: MetaCoordinates = input;
```

Comment: Awesome answer and cute lion!!